# Prove that W is a subspace and find its spanning set

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be the space of $2x2$ matrices. Let $W=\{X\in V | AX=XA\}$ and $A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$

Prove that $W$ is a subspace and show it's spanning set.

My attempt:

I showed that W is a subset of V and it is a space by showing that it is an abelian group under matrix addition and showed that the assumptions of scalar multiplication holds.

How can I show the spanning set? Where should I start?

Comment: Perhaps write out the eqations of what it means for a matrix $X$ to commute with $A$, and solve it as 8 linear equations in 8 variables (the entries of $X$) should work?

Comment: I think it would be 4 equations 4 unknowns. But I do agree such approach seems promising.

Comment: I think it's gonna work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 &x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \end{pmatrix} $, and $AX=XA$, then

$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1-2x_3 & x_2-2x_4\\ 3x_3 & 3x_4 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & -2x_1+3x_2 \\ x_3 & -2x_3+3x_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

So
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{ll} 
x_3=0 & \ \\
x_2-x_1+x_4=0 & \
\end{array} \right.$$

Therefore $$\begin{split}\lbrace X: AX=XA\rbrace &=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x_1&x_2\\x_3&x_4 \end{pmatrix}:x_3=0, x_4=x_1-x_2\right\}\\{}\\ &=x_1e_1+x_2e_2+(x_1-x_2)e_4\end{split}$$